XSLT: find the node with an attribute value "lower than but closest to" my input value
I have an XML that contains a series of topic nodes that have a version attribute. Versioning is numeric. The topics are linked: we have topic nodes with the same ID, and different versions.
I want to select one of these topic nodes: the topic whose version is closest to, and equal or lower than, my input variable.
XML:
<topics>
  <topic id="1" version="6"/>
  <topic id="1" version="3"/>
  <topic id="1" version="1"/>
</topics>

If my input variable is 7, I want to select the topic with version="6".
If my input variable is 6, I want to select the topic with version="6".
If my input variable is 5, I want to select the topic with version="3".
Something like this would work:
<xsl:variable name="ver" select="7"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//topic[@version = $ver]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//topic[@version = $ver]">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="//topic[@version = $ver -1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//topic[@version = $ver -1]">
    </xsl:when>
    ...
</xsl:choose>

But I have 16 values for 'version' and there will be more in the future. Is there a way to replace this choose/when with something that does not have to enumerate every possible value?
(using Saxon, can use XSLT 2 and 3)

In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

In XSLT 2 and later you can use <xsl:variable name="max" select="max(//topic/@version[. &lt; $ver])"/> and then select //topic[@version = $max].
In XSLT 4 there is/will be a function highest https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview.html#func-highest so that you could select e.g. highest(//topic[@version < $ver], (), function($t) { $t/@version }) in XPath or highest(//topic[@version &lt; $ver], (), function($t) { $t/@version }) in XSLT.

Another option is to sort the topics and select the first (or last) one that conforms to the threshold:
<xsl:variable name="ver" select="7"/>

<xsl:variable name="sorted-topics">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="/topics/topic">
        <xsl:sort select="@version"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:copy-of select="$sorted-topics/topic[@version &lt; $ver][last()]"/>

